# What's a smart way of merging two nested dictionaries of depth 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What is the "best" way to merge two nested dictionaries of depth 2?

For example, I'd like to merge the following two dictionaries:

```
dicA: - user1 {name,age,sex}
      - user2 {name,age,sex}

dicB  - user1 {location,job}
      - user3 {location,job}
```

In order to get:

```
dic_merged - user1 {name,age,sex,location,job}
           - user2 {name,age,sex}
           - user3 {location,job}
```

Note that the subvalues in dicA and dicB will always be disjoint.
Currently, I'm using:

```
def merge(dicA,dicB):
    for user in dicB:
        if user in dicA:
            dicA[user].update(dicB[user])
        else:
            dicA[user] = dicB[user]
    return dicA
```

Is there an alternative to update or a one-liner that can merge nested dictionaries?

Comment: Where did `def` go bro?

Comment: You could have given actual input and output. It would have been easier to verify then.

Comment: def didn't make the pseudocode cut. Apologies.

Comment: What do you mean by the actual input/output? Because I actually have a dozen "subfields" in my dictionaries, and I thought it would have made it less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (bottom of section):

```
def merge(d1, d2):
     return {key: dict(d1.get(key, {}).items() + d2.get(key, {}).items()) for key in d1.keys() + d2.keys()}
```

This creates a list of all keys to use in a dict comprehension, and uses the more robust [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to prevent errors if key is only in the one of the `dict`s.

---

For Python 3 [`dict view`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) objects are returned from `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()`, so you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (or wrap in  each `dict view` object in `list`):

```
def merge(d1, d2):
     return {key: dict(chain(d1.get(key, {}).items(), d2.get(key, {}).items())) for key in chain(d1.keys(), d2.keys())}
```

**Note:** Using [`collections.defaultdict(dict)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would make the whole thing nicer.

Comment: I don't think this works for Python 3: `d1.keys()` etc returns a `dict_keys` object and these can't be concatenated

Comment: @xnx added method for python 3.

Comment: `list(d1.keys()) + list(d2.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's too much wrong with the way you suggest, though I would use a `try...except` clause:

```
dicA = {'user1': { 'name': 'John', 'age': 45, 'sex': 'M'},
        'user2': { 'name': 'Jane', 'age': 42, 'sex': 'F'}}

dicB = {'user1': {'job': 'janitor', 'location': 'HK'},
        'user3': {'job': 'Python-wrangler', 'location': 'NY'}}

def merge(dicA,dicB):
    for user, d in dicB.items():
        try:
            dicA[user].update(dicB[user])
        except KeyError:
            dicA[user] = d
    return dicA
```

The result is then, for `dicA`:

```
    {'user1': {'job': 'janitor', 'age': 45, 'name': 'John',
     'location': 'HK', 'sex': 'M'},
     'user2': {'age': 42, 'name': 'Jane', 'sex': 'F'},
     'user3': {'job': 'Python-wrangler', 'location': 'NY'}}
```